# I am having trouble getting my function mygame() to run in my Javascript program

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, if-statement, charat

I am creating a wheel of fortune like game where a player may have 10 guesses to guess a hidden word and I am using charAt and for loops for the guessing. When I go to click on the button in my html the program will not run.

```
function myGame()
{
var name = prompt("What is your name");
document.getElementById("user_name").innerHTML = "Welcome " + name + " to Wheel of Fortune";    
const d = new Date();
document.getElementById("today_date").innerHTML = "Today's date is " + d;

var count = 0;
var phrase = "javascriptisneat";
var word = "";
var checkWin = false;
var w_lgth = phrase.length;
var guess;
var correct_guess = false;

for (var i = 0; i < w_lgth; i++)
word = word + "/ ";
document.getElementById("wheel_game").innerHTML = word;
while (checkWin == false && count < 10)
{
correct_guess = false;  
guess = prompt("Guess a letter");
for (var j = 0; j < w_lgth; j++)
{
if(guess == phrase.charAT(j))
{
correct_guess = true;
var set = 2 * j;
word = setCharAt(word, set, guess);
   }
    }
    document.getElementById("wheel_game").innerHTML = word;
    checkWin = checkWord(phrase, word);
    if(checkWin == true)
    {
    document.getElementById("game_result").innerHTML = ("you are a winner");

else if (checkWin == false)
{
document.getElementById("game_result").innerHTML = ("You Lose");
if(correct_guess == false)
count = count + 1;
 }  
 }  
 }

function checkWord(phrase, o_word) { var c_word; c_word = o_word; c_word = o_word.replace(/ /g, ""); if(phrase == c_word) return true; else  return false; }

function setCharAt(str, index, chr) { if(index > str.length-1) return str; 
return str.substr(0,index) + chr + str.substr(index+1);
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>CIS 223 Chapter 7 program</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    
    <body>
<h1>Welcome Player</h1>
<p> Click to begin </p>
<button type="button" onclick="myGame();">Begin</button>

<p id="user_name"> </p> <br>
<p id="today_date"> </p> <br>

<div id="wheel_game"> </div> <br>
<div id ="game_result"> </div>

<script src="myScript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried commenting out parts of the code to see what will run and what won't and it seems that the program will run up until the first else if that is on line 39. After that though the program will not run. I checked and I should have the curly brackets in the right places and am not missing any. I am using a external JavaScript file but I know this should not matter.

Comment: The brackets/indentation around `if(checkWin == true) ... / else if (checkWin == false)` seem suspect.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close the curly braces at line 37 of the if statement. I closed the curly braces and it worked for me